# Dynamo throughput not reaching provisioned level - using Hive and EMR 5.2

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-dynamodb, hiveql, emr

We're using Hive running on EMR 5.2.0 to run many many files to a Dynamo table.  The provisioned throughput on the table is 3000 writes per second.

We are only able to hit 2000 writes regardless of the throughput percentage that is set in the Hive script.

The Hive execution engine is set to mr, and the dynamo.throughput.read.percent is set to 1.0.
We use the EMR to run the step using command-runner.  Thus far we're unable to find any reasons why it's only using 2/3 of the provisioned writes.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edited to add hive script:

```
    SET hive.execution.engine=mr;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS s3_import;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dynamo_import;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3_import(fld string, dateRef string)
ROW FORMAT
DELIMITED FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ','
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LOCATION 's3n://${s3Path}';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dynamo_import(fld string, dateRef string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = '${tableName}',
"dynamodb.throughput.read.percent" = '${rp}',
"dynamodb.throughput.write.percent" = '${wp}',
"dynamodb.column.mapping" = "fld:fld,dateRef:dateRef");

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dynamo_import SELECT * FROM s3_import;
```

Edit:
If I run two applications in parallel that use 0.5 as the write throughput we're able to achieve the optimal writes within the provisioned amount, this leads me to think that there may be a setting o the cluster that is causing the problem?

Comment: are you uniformly reading from the partitions on the table? It may be that you're exceeding throughput on a partition, for example

Comment: @Henry - Hi, I'll be honest and say I'm not sure.  I've added the script if that'll help answer your question - assuming you wouldn't mind taking a peek that is

Comment: what is the size of the table? also, provisioned read/write throughput?

Comment: @ketanvijayvargiya - the size of the table that we're writing to is currently 20GB, it's throughput for writes is 3000 per second, reads is 100 but we don't read from it.

Answer (score 0):

The read and write percent settings are *best effort* rate limiters. The DynamoDB connector estimates the read and write capacity based on an item size heuristic and may not always get it right.  That's why you can actually "over provision" reads and writes up to 1.5 (150%) so you should try that.

The other thing that can actually cause your write capacity to not hit the provisioned limit is the presence of hot-spots in the key space. If there are more items in one partition than others then the utilization will be uneven and you will hit throttling on (one or two partitions) even though you're not using the full provisioned rate for the whole table. With 3000 write capacity units and some reads, your table has at least 4 partitions so this can definitely be a factor.